# MVC: Unable to figure out how this code is hitting stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm reviewing some C# mvc code that returns data from a stored procedure but I'm unable to locate WHERE this code is hitting that stored procedure.  I've done a search of the entire vs.net solution for the stored procedure name & the only mention of the SP doesn't get hit when I step through this code.  I need to know where & how this code is hitting that SP in order to make a change.

The below code is only a few snippets of a MUCH larger project & I'm sure I'm leaving off the snippet that leads to the stored procedure, but I hope this is enough to provide some insight into what may be happening.  If you need to see more code, please let me know & I'll update.  I've tried to comment as much of the code as possible:

```
 //We start here.       
 //About 15 lines down, you'll see a "using" statement. 
 //When I first step into that line, the "data" variable is NULL.  
 //I hit F11 one more time to step into another line, and the code jumps into the 
 //ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData class.  Following that, it hits
 // the line that reads "telerehabProviderExclusions = data.PullList();" 
 //and the "data" variable suddenly has all values from the stored procedure :-( 
public bool IsValidForTelerehab(Models.ClaimOrder.ClaimOrder claimOrder)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        if (claimOrder != null)
        {
            if (!claimOrder.IsBillDirect)
            {                    
                List<ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusion> telerehabProviderExclusions = null;                    
                using (ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData data = new ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData())
                {
                    //once in here, the "data" variable has already 
                   //somehow hit the stored procedure.
                    telerehabProviderExclusions = data.PullList();
                }
```

Here's the ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData class, which gets hit during the above "using" statement.:

```
public class ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData : IDisposable
{

    #region Private Properties

    //From the "using" statement, the below line is the ONLY line
    // of the code in this class that 
    //gets hit.  It then returns back into the "using" statement and suddenly,
    // has all values from the stored procedure.
    private List<ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusion> telerehabProviderExclusion = null;

    private List<ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusion> TelerehabProviderExclusion
    {
        get
        {                
            if (telerehabProviderExclusion == null)
            {
                BuildList();
            }
            return telerehabProviderExclusion;
        }            
    }
```

Any idea as to what I may be missing?

Thanks

Comment: `it hits
 // the line that reads "telerehabProviderExclusions = data.PullList();" 
 //and the "data" variable suddenly has all values from the stored procedure`....so, what is in the PullList() method, then? Seems like that would be the place...or are you saying that the data is populated _before_ `PullList()` is executed? What about `BuildList()`? What does that do?

Comment: It populates before PullList().  It goes from the line reading "using (ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData data = new ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData())", over to "private List<ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusion> telerehabProviderExclusion = null;" in the "ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData" class, and then back into the PullList().  By the time it reaches PullList() however, the "data" variable is already populated.

Comment: And ClaimOrderTelerehabProviderExclusionData does not have any kind of constructor which might start to try and populate the data?

Comment: You stripped out the code which loads the data when asking the question, then ask what you're missing?